# Convolution of a piecewise function

Tags: r, integral

Suppose I have two functions, f1 and f2, which is defined piecewise from a list of enumerated steps / jump points.

```
set.seed(1729)
n = 100
x1 = cumsum(runif(n))
x2 = cumsum(runif(n))
val1 = cumsum(runif(n))
val2 = cumsum(runif(n))

f1_list = data.frame(f = val1, x = x1)
f2_list = data.frame(f = val2, x = x2)
```

For simplicity, let's assume both are right-continuous. The first few values look like

```
> head(f1_list)
          f         x
1 0.1371357 0.5852396
2 0.4752026 1.0226336
3 1.0987574 1.5955279
4 1.9413884 1.9487419
5 2.0264764 2.8100133
6 2.3962088 3.2208168
> head(f2_list)
          f         x
1 0.3294329 0.5373382
2 0.8749826 1.3104701
3 1.5604155 2.0395473
4 1.9325968 2.9311143
5 2.3134223 3.2732812
6 2.4605212 3.6648067
```

I want to compute the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), g(t) = (f1*f2)(t). Programmatically, this does not seem like an easy task, because not only do we need to keep track of all the jump-points, but *also in reverse*, by the definition of convolution. What I've tried is

```
#############
#Say, t = 10#
#############
t = 10
f2_list$x_rev = t - f2_list$x
```

At which point, I'm stuck, since I don't know how to match up the corresponding intervals of x values for f1_list and f2_list.

Comment: To perform convolution over discrete samples, the time differences need to be uniform. So you probably need to interpolate the functions and get the values at equally spaced intervals. Then just the `f` values can be convolved.